# Gradle task to change a boolean in build config

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I would like to create a very simple task which change a boolean in my gradle config.

I work on an Android application which can be run with several profiles, and for each build a need to specify if in my code the app must fake the bluetooth or not.

My gradle (relevant code) :

```
def fakeBluetooth = "true"

buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig android.signingConfigs.debug
        buildConfigField "boolean", "fakeBluetooth", fakeBluetooth
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        signingConfig android.signingConfigs.release
        buildConfigField "boolean", "fakeBluetooth", fakeBluetooth
    }
}

task noFakeBluetooth {
    fakeBluetooth = "false"
}
```

Example of use in my java code :

```
if (BuildConfig.fakeBluetooth) {
    processFictiveBluetoothService();
} else {
    // other case
}
```

Examples of use in command line :

```
./gradlew iDebug noFakeBluetooth
```

and

```
./gradlew iDebug
```

Problem : in both cases the value of fakeBluetooth is always "true" (with or without "noFakeBluetooth" in cmd line).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use project properties to pass the value:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig android.signingConfigs.debug
        buildConfigField "boolean", "fakeBluetooth", fakeBluetooth()
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        signingConfig android.signingConfigs.release
        buildConfigField "boolean", "fakeBluetooth", fakeBluetooth()
    }
}

def fakeBluetooth() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("fakeBluetooth")
    return value != null ? value : "true"
}
```

And then you can pass the property with:

```
./gradlew iDebug -PfakeBluetooth=true
```

Answer (score 2):

This works

```
 android.defaultConfig.buildConfigField "String", "value", "1"
```

Comment: It is also a solution. Depend of the implem... Thanks

Comment: In my case I'm simply using it to set configuration parameters within tasks

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct approach would be to define resource value for buildTypes or productFlavours:

`resValue "string", "key", "value"`

then read out from it inside your code like:
`getResources().getString(R.string.key);`