# Android Gradle: call buildConfigield inside gradle task or method

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-task, android-buildconfig

I'm trying to add BuildConfig variable using gradle.
I see that buildConfigField is valid when I call it on
gradle `buildTypes: release/debug` and also on `defaultConfig`

but I'm trying to create this inside gradle task. for example:

```
task myTask{
    buildConfigField 'String', 'Test', '"value"'
}
```

and then call my task.
but in that case when I call myTask, gradle is failed and I'm getting:

```
"could not find method buildConfigField"
```

is there any option to call `buildConfigField` and make it work inside task?

Comment: Take a look here, it might help you find a way to solve this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474958/gradle-task-to-change-a-boolean-in-build-config

Comment: @Skenia tnx! it's helped!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Skenia suggesting this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474958/gradle-task-to-change-a-boolean-in-build-config)

I was able to find a solution, using the answer of Marian Klühspies there.

so for anyone who encounter this in the future, you can use this

```
android.defaultConfig.buildConfigField "String", "value", "1"
```

inside tasks and this will work